# writing a rspec test to add an item to a hash

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am getting a NoMethodError
for my code but I have defined the add method it says it is missing.
I am trying to add an item to a hash that already exists.
 The hash is the dishes and I am trying to use the add method.

The test:

```
require 'menu'

describe Menu do

    it 'has a menu' do
        expect(subject.respond_to?(:dishes)).to be true
    end

    it 'displays dishes and prices' do
        expect(subject.dishes).to eq [
            { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95 },
            { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
            { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
            { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 }
        ]
    end

    it 'can add dishes to it' do
        menu = Menu.new 
        menu.add_dish("Icecream", 4.80)
        expect(subject.dishes).to eq [
            { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95 },
            { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
            { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
            { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 },
            { name: 'icecream', price: 4.80 }
        ]
    end
end
```

the methods

```
class Menu
   def initialize
     @dishes = []
   end

   def dishes
     @dishes = [
        { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95  },
        { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
        { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
        { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 }
     ]
   end

   def add_dish(name, price)
     @dishes << { name: name, price: price }
   end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you maybe give The entire spec and menu class? Also the stacktrace of the error? Looks like you should be doing something like `@dishes << {name: name, price: price}` in your add method, but can't really tell what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks the error I am getting is not a stack it is a 

    Menu can add dishes to it
     Failure/Error: Menu.add("Icecream", 4.80)
     NoMethodError:
      undefined method `add' for Menu:Class   

I will update my question with all the code now

Comment: Can you post the code for your whole menu class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of [Ryan-Neal Mes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808919/676788) solves the NoMethodError, but there are many other problems in your code.

1. You repeat your self, and you should make your code dry (Don't Repeat Yourself principle)
2. while you want to add a hash to the list of dishes which is it self a list of hashes, you force the object that needs to call the add method to provide the parameters in a particular order, than the method constructs the hash, so every time you need to call it you need to return to it to see the order of parameters.
3. the `dishes` method is wrong, because each time you call it, it assigns the initial array to the `@dishes` variable. In this case the `add_dishes` method will have no effect, since the added dish will be deleted the next time you call the `dishes` method.
4. your examples are not expressive, so if a test did not pass, you cannot know from the printed messages what's the problem. OK, this is not a big deal in this small example, but in a big application, specs expressiveness is of a higher value.

here the test examples

```
require 'menu'

describe Menu do
  # every time you call the function dishes in an example
  # it will be declared and it will return this array
  let :dishes do
    [
      { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95 },
      { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
      { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
      { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 }
    ]
  end

  # explicit definition of the subject
  subject { Menu.new }

  # a shorter yet more expressive version of
  # expect(subject.respond_to?(:dishes)).to be true
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:dishes) }

  # You should always group the examples that test 
  # the same method
  describe '#dishes' do
    # it 'displays dishes and prices' do
    it 'returns the list of dishes' do
      expect(subject.dishes).to eq dishes
    end
  end

  describe "#add_dish" do
    # it 'can add dishes to it' do
    it "adds the given dish to the list of dishes" do
      new_dish = {name: 'salad', price: 4.0 }
      expect {
        subject.add_dish(new_dish)
      }.to change(subject.dishes, :count).by(1)
      expect(subject.dishes).to include new_dish
    end
  end
end
```

so here is the class definition

```
class Menu
  # you don't need to declare the method dishes
  # since this is what attr_reader will do
  attr_reader :dishes

   def initialize
     # this will set the @dishes only once
     # but you code @dishes = [...] will return
     # the same list every time you call it and
     # all the dishes you add through the #add method
     # will be deleted.
     @dishes = [
        { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95  },
        { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
        { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
        { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 }
     ]
   end

   # dish is a hash {name: '', price: ''} 
   def add_dish(dish)
     @dishes << dish
   end
end
```

so now run `rspec --format doc --color` and see who expressive are the messages.

Comment: Big Kudos to you for your awesome help! I am New to ruby and was totally stuck on why my hash was not working, and had almost given up! Thank you so much for taking the time to help out!

Comment: @Stacca Never-mind,  We are a community, and it's our duty to give help when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see your problem. You need to initialize your menu. `Add` is not a static method. So you need something like,

```
Menu.new.add(blah, blah)
```

Look at:

```
Menu.add("Icecream", 4.80)
```

This method is wrong. It needs to be:

```
Menu.new.add("Icecream", 4.80)
```

or you need something like:

```
menu = Menu.new
menu.add("Icecream", 4.80)
```

Comment: Note that if you did want a static method then you would use `def self.add(name, price)` but I don't think you need it from what I can see.

Comment: Thank you the def self.add has helped,actually but not solved it.  As the new dish (cream has not added to the hash) but getting there. thanks

Comment: Read the answer it will help a bit more. You don't want to use self.add. You want to change your spec where you are saying `Menu.add` to `Menu.new.add`

Comment: Thanks but both those return the error

 undefined method `add' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to get this working without your code, but the problem is pretty straight forward.

Try the edited code below. Note the changes to the spec initialize the menu and add method adds to the instance variable @dishes.

```
require 'menu'

describe Menu do
   it 'displays dishes and prices' do
    expect(Menu.new.dishes).to eq [
      { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95 },
      { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
      { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
      { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 }
    ]
  end
  it 'can add dishes to it' do
   menu = Menu.new.add("Icecream", 4.80)
   expect(menu.dishes).to eq [
    { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95 },
    { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
    { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
    { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 },
    { name: 'icecream', price: 4.80 }
  ]
  end
end

class Menu
   def initialize
     @dishes = []
   end

   def dishes
    @dishes ||=
    [
      { name: 'Burger', price: 10.95  },
      { name: 'Pizza', price: 14.00 },
      { name: 'Salad', price: 7.60 },
      { name: 'fries', price: 2.90 }
    ]
  end

  def add(name, price)
    @dishes << { name: name, price: price }
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a couple of problems with this code. First, because the `add` method is not declared as a class method (i.e. `def self.add`) you can't call it as a class method (as you've seen, `Menu.add` says NoMethodError). Instead, you'll need to create an instance of the Menu class in your test, perhaps using `let`:

```
describe Menu do
  let(:menu) { Menu.new }

  it 'can add dishes to it' do
    menu.add("Icecream", 4.80)
    # test your expectations...
  end
end
```

Lastly, as the `add` method is currently defined, it doesn't modify `@dishes` but rather just returns a new hash, so your expectation will fail. You'll need to make the `add` method append the values, perhaps like this:

```
def add(name, , price)
  @dishes << {name: name, price: price}
end
```